# How do I determine the cause of a SCSI device reset?

Tags: linux, devices, block-device, scsi

I found this in /var/log/messages:

```
Jul 27 03:59:46 localhost kernel: sd 3:0:1:0: [sdd] SCSI device reset on scsi3:1
```

I don't see any other error logs to indicate **why** the reset occurred.

How do I determine the cause of this SCSI device reset?

Note:
I'm running Linux CentOS 7 as a virtual machine on top of VMware's ESX hypervisor.

Comment: Is this a singlel, directly attached disk, or is it a RAID unit, or on a SAN, or is it a virtual disk implemented by VMware?

Comment: Is it a physical HDD disk connected by an HBA (non RAID controller).